# Find out how a CSS file comes back again no matter what I do

Tags: php, wordpress, file, templates, wordpress-theming

I am working with a WordPress website using a template called Avada. I want to edit a input tag style but there is a file that does not matter what I do it comes back like it was before.

This makes me suspect that there is a php file somewhere with a function that generates this file. It could also be worse if this is coming from a API. The question here is: How do I find out what is exactly going on?

Comment: Use a developer tool, check where the style is being applied, check to see if there is content being pulled via the networks-tab, and so on.

Comment: it says initiator index , what does that mean?

Comment: What says "initiator index"? Where do you see it? Information is key, when you're trying to explain something to someone not seeing what you're seeing.

Comment: in the network, take a look to this screen shot: http://prntscr.com/ezcjgt . I took a look to index file of my theme and it shows this http://prntscr.com/ezcjxy

Comment: Ah, that kind of initiator - that just shows what file calls the other file - which would be index when you load the front page. What happens if you delete or rename the CSS-file in the folder? (Only delete it after copying it, or making sure you can restore it, of course).

Comment: I already did that. What happened was that a identical new file took place

Comment: Well, then it's definitely either loaded from somewhere, or being generated - in that case, you need to dig into the code of the theme itself.

Comment: this code prntscr.com/ezcjxy tells me where to look for but I don't know php, where should I look next?

Comment: It actually doesn't, unless they can't code for shit. The information about the CSS-file should be found in the header (the `get_header()` function) should contain the code for the CSS - however, I do not know Avada-theme, so they might have put CSS-calls in the code directly... if so, find another theme. And you will just have to search through the theme-files - load all of them into a proper text-editor, and do an overall search for specifics (like a classname or ID or something CSS-specific).

Comment: You are right, they are calling that file from header.php  , here: http://prntscr.com/ezcp81   . @junkfoodjunkie I guess you found the answer

Comment: Seems like that is part of Fusion-builder https://avada.theme-fusion.com/fusion-builder-2/ - I would look into the Avada-documentation, maybe there are built-in functions for adding/modifying CSS for the theme.